# Find rpm dependencies using python yum/rpm API?

Tags: python, rpm, yum

It seems like it should be available, but I just can't seem to find it.

Something like:

```
pkg = rpm.Package(name="some package")
dependencies = pkg.dependencies()
```

Is there something like this available, that would be cleaner than what I'm doing now?

Currently, I'm wrapping the rpm command with subprocess and manually parsing the output:

```
cmd = "rpm -qRp {file} | sort | uniq".format(file=filename)
cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
# ... long parse of cmd_output
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following scipt will list all Requires from a package provided on commandline (full path to rpm file):

```
import os
import rpm
import sys

ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
fd = os.open(sys.argv[1], os.O_RDONLY)
h = ts.hdrFromFdno(fd)
os.close(fd)

for dep in h[rpm.RPMTAG_REQUIRENAME]:
    print dep
```

Or alternatively to work with package in rpm database:

```
import os
import rpm
import sys

ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
mi = ts.dbMatch('name', sys.argv[1])
for ind in range(mi.count()):
    h = mi.next()
    for dep in h[rpm.RPMTAG_REQUIRENAME]:
        print dep
```